# How to publish/subscribe a python “list of list” as topic in ROS

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, ros, rospy

I am new to ROS and rospy, and I am not familiar with non-simple data type as topic.

I want to build a ROS node as both a subscriber and publisher: it receives a topic (a list of two `float64`), and uses a function (say `my_function`) which returns a list of lists of `float64`, then publish this list of list as a topic.

To do this, I built a node as following:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from myfile import my_function
import rospy
import numpy as np

pub = None
sub = None

def callback(req):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.block
    lon = np.float64(req.b)
    lat = np.float64(req.a)
    point_list = my_function(lon, lat, db)
    pub.publish(point_list)

def calculator():
    global sub, pub
    rospy.init_node('calculator', anonymous=True)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('output_data', list)
    # Listen
    sub = rospy.Subscriber('input_data', list, callback)
    print "Calculation finished. \n"
    ros.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        calculator()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

I know clearly that `list` in Subscriber and Publisher is not a message data, but I cannot figure out how to fix it since it is not an integer nor list of integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can complicate yourself by defining a new **ros** Type in the **msg** OR use the default and easy to implement **std_msgs** Type, maybe will be useful to use a json module, so you serialize the data before publishing and deserialize it back on the other side after receiving...

the rest Pub/Sub , topic and handlers remain the same :)

Comment: I'm very new to ROS and am also trying to build a ROS node as both a subscriber and publisher (regardless of the topic's data type). Is it recognized as good practice to achieve this by having global `pub` and `sub` variables? Or would it be better to pass `pub` as an argument to the `callback`?

Answer (score 5):

[This post](https://answers.ros.org/question/67273/how-to-publish-a-two-dimensional-array-msg-with-int8-type/) on the ROS forums gives you most of what you need. [This](https://answers.ros.org/question/9471/how-to-recieve-an-array-over-publisher-and-subscriber-python/) is also useful. You can [define a new message type](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) `FloatList.msg` with the following specification:

```
float64[] elements
```

And then a second message type `FloatArray.msg` defined as:

```
FloatList[] lists
```

Then your function could look like:

```
def callback(req):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.block
    lon = np.float64(req.b)
    lat = np.float64(req.a)
    point_list = my_function(lon, lat, db)
    float_array = FloatArray()
    for i in range(len(point_list)):
        float_list = FloatList()
        float_list.elements = point_list[i]
        float_array.lists[i] = float_list
    pub.publish(float_array)
```

And then you can unpack it with:

```
def unpack_callback(float_array_msg):
    for lst in float_array_msg.lists:
        for e in lst.elements:
            print "Here is an element: %f" % e
```

In general, it is recommended you put ROS related questions on the [ROS Forums](https://answers.ros.org/questions/) since you are way more likely to get an answer to your question there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the solution, I thought about organizing it a bit more

1. Create a file `FloatArray.msg` in your `catkin_ws` in the src folder where you have all your other message files.
2. Build your env using `catkin_make` or `catkin build`.
3. In your script (e.g. Python script) import the message type and use it in the subscriber e.g.

   `joint_state_publisher_Unity = rospy.Publisher("/joint_state_unity", FloatArray , queue_size = 10)`

specific case (bonus :)): if you are using Unity and ROS# build the message in Unity